# Java Netbeans Derby how can I check if a database is encrypted?

Tags: java, database, encryption, netbeans, derby

If I have a database created by right clicking on Services TAB on Netbeans how can I know if the database is encrypted or not?

I mean, I go to Netbeans, Services, Databases, right click on Java DB and CREATE DATABASE, but Netbeans only ask me the database name, user and password but didnt ask if I want the database encrypted or not.

So I guess we have a default state but I cant find where to change on Netbeans.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to create an encrypted database? Or do you want to ask if an existing database is encrypted?

Comment: Hello Bryan, the second one. "Or do you want to ask if an existing database is encrypted?" Thanks

Comment: Hello, I still looking for this answer... I cant find info about how to know if a database is encrypted or not.

Comment: I'm not sure that I know an easy way to tell that. You could try asking on the Derby mailing lists at Apache. Another possibility would be to try to open the database, and if you fail because you don't have the right encryption key, well, then it was encrypted.